# Can't build Maven project in Netbeans due to dependencies

Tags: maven, netbeans, build, dependencies

I have a problem when building my Maven project in Netbeans. When on my stationary computer it works just fine, but on my laptap I cant get it to work. I get the following error:

Failed to execute goal on project SnakeAppWebpage: Could not resolve dependencies for project se.chalmers.snake:SnakeAppWebpage:war:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.apache.derby:derbyclient:jar:10.6.1.0 (compile), org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.2.0 (provided), org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.0.3 (provided), org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor:jar:2.2.0 (provided), javax:javaee-web-api:jar:6.0 (provided), junit:junit:jar:4.8.2 (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.2.0: Could not transfer artifact org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:pom:2.2.0 from/to eclipselink (http://ftp.ing.umu.se/mirror/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

I've already added all the jar files manually but it still doesn't work. I have the same OS and Netbeans version on both computers. Also when I try to build the project on my laptop Netbeans tries to download the dependencies from the specified repositories before showing me the error. The repositories URL's are valid. When building on my other computer it doesnt do this BS, it just launches the application.

Answer (score 1):

Maven only needs to download any specific library/dependency one time per machine. On your desktop computer it probably downloaded these repositories at some point in the past and has them still stored on your computer. However, on your laptop it looks like it is having trouble retrieving the repositories from the remote store (check your internet connection? "Error transferring file: Connection timed out" appears to be the pertinent error). If you have added the jars manually, make sure you added them in the correct maven repository location and followed the proper directory structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I have no internet connection issues, however after more research into the "Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect" message I find out the problem is most certainly caused due to my computer somehow being behind a proxy. The solution, I think, is to edit the settings.xml in the .m2 folder to allow my proxy.
What I dont know though is how to find out about my proxy information that I need to fill in in settings.xml. Im very bad at networking stuff and I find myself rather clueless.

Comment: open your network settings in your web browser and see if there are proxy settings defined there.  if so, you should be able to use those same settings.